# Revert `display: none` on elements to original value

Tags: javascript, html, css

#### explanation

I have a script that hides elements, if the user does not have the permission to view/use it. I set `display: none` for those elements.

Now later, when I want to show the elements again, I don't just want to set `display: block` or something, because maybe the elements original `display` value was something other than `block`. Is there a way I can revert the display or set it to a neutral value?

#### example

E.g. `<div class="fancy-class">...</div>` If `fancy-class` has `display` set to `inline-block` and I just set it to `block` with my script, that will break the ui.

#### attempts

I have tried using `display: initial` but that resets it to the HTML-element's initial styling - not the class's styling.
I hope I don't have to keep the original values in an array and then apply them again. Doesn't seem nice.

Comment: If you want to reset `style.display` to its original value use: `element.style.display = ""`

Comment: Store it in as a data-attriute to element by getting display property using window.getComputedStyle on page load and then retrieve it and apply when you need it.

Comment: @KooiInc simple as that - it worked just the way I wanted - thanks!

Comment: @jeetaz also interesting, but I feel like the other option is simpler, thank you though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use: `element.style.display = ""` to reset `style.display` of an element

```js
(() => {
  const displayState = reset => 
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div"))
      .forEach( el => el.style.display = reset ? "" : "none" );
    //                                           ^ restore original display state
  document.querySelector("#showAll").addEventListener("click", () => displayState(true));
  document.querySelector("#hideAll").addEventListener("click", () => displayState());
})();
```

```css
#first, #second, #third {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="first">[First]</div>
<div id="second">[Second]</div>
<div id="third">[Third]</div>
<button id="showAll">show divs</button>
<button id="hideAll">hide divs</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before setting display to none, you can save it, and apply it back.

```
var display = document.getElementsByClassName("fancy-class").style.display;
document.getElementById("fancy-class").style.display = none;
```

Set above saved attribute.

```
document.getElementById("fancy-class").style.display = display;
```